# system.net.http.httprequestexception: an error occurred while sending the request. Visual studio

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, xamarin, mysql-error-1064

I am working with visual studio 2017 and MySQL. I recently had a problem with my computer hard-disk so had to change it. I downloaded visual studio and MySQL all over again.I had my code on a pen-drive so I imported the code back into visual studio and recreated the tables for MySQL. I successfully connected my visual studio to MySQL. This is my code.

**Welcome Page**

```
 public async Task<List<string>> UserNumber()
    {
        MainUserDataRestClient<string> restClient = new MainUserDataRestClient<string>();
        var GetNumber = await restClient.GetAsync();
        return GetNumber;
    }



    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        List<string> Number = new List<string>();
        Number = await UserNumber();
        await MainProgressBar.ProgressTo(0.8, 1000, Easing.Linear);

        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage())
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#35ddcf")
        };
        int i = Number.Count;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            await  MainProgressBar.ProgressTo(0.8, 1000, Easing.Linear);
            App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
        else
        {
            await MainProgressBar.ProgressTo(0.8, 1000, Easing.Linear);
            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage())
            { BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#35ddcf") };
        }
    }
}
```

**Restcient**

```
  public class MainUserDataRestClient<T>
{
    private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost:57645/api/MainUserData/";


    public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync()
    {

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);

        var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

        return taskModels;
    } }
```

**Controller**

```
 public class MainUserDataController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/MainUserData
    [HttpGet]
    public List<string> Get()
    {
        string sqlstring = "server=localhost; port=3306 ; user id =root;Password=;Database=test;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlstring);
        MainPhoneNumber MNP = new MainPhoneNumber();

        MySqlParameter param = new MySqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@id";
        param.Value = MNP.PhoneNumber;


        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM test.maintable where Telephone = @id ";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        MySqlDataReader MSQLRD = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<string> GetBizList = new List<string>();

        if (MSQLRD.HasRows)
        {

            while (MSQLRD.Read())
            {
                string BV;
                BV = (MSQLRD["Telephone"].ToString());
                GetBizList.Add(BV);
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
        return GetBizList;
    } }
```

When I run the code, I am unable to retrieve the data from the MySQL database and I get this exception.

> Unhandled Exception : system.net.http.httprequestexception: an error occurred while sending the request

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a database error. Seems that the error is coming from this line:

```
var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);
```

I don't have much information on your running environment, but it seems from the url that you are using iis-Express. The first thing to look at, would be the url:

```
private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost:57645/api/MainUserData/";
```

Is the port correct in your new setup, or has it changed and you are trying to hit a non existing url?

Second thing to look at, is werther or not you can hit a breakpoint in your controller. If yes, do you have any errors/ exceptions in there?

Add more information if the above suggestions did not work, so that we can better help you.

Comment: How do  know if the Url has changed?

Comment: I am using iis-Express, just as you stated.

Comment: When you startup your api, a tray icon with iis express will start and a url can be seen on hover with the current port.

Comment: The Url is the same.

Comment: Please, Is there any other suggestion you might have? I need help.

Comment: Check if you can hit a controller breakpoint. Know how to setup one?

Comment: No, I don't know how to setup a break-point in my controller.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019

Comment: Okay, I have figured it out. So now where should I place the breakpoint?

Comment: In your controller code. Check if the action is activated and the code runs. If yes, check if an exception is thrown at any line.

Comment: After I placed the breakpoint on the line and run the code, this is the exception I received `Resolved pending breakpoint at 'RestClient.cs:743,1' to void bizclos1.View.MainUserDataRestClient<string>.<GetAsync>d__1.MoveNext () [0x0001a].
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'RestClient.cs:743,13' to void bizclos1.View.MainUserDataRestClient<T_REF>.<GetAsync>d__1.MoveNext () [0x0001a].`